# Kafka producer config metadata.broker.list with url

Tags: java, apache-kafka

I have setup a kafka server with 3 brokers. I want to send a message from my computer to these three brokers, but I already configured each broker for a url like `abc.com/kafka1/ abc.com/kafka2/ abc.com/kafka3/` in `ngix`.

How do I use these urls in the `metadata.broker.list` property? My code is below.

```
package com.xxx.x.kafka.producer;

import kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer;
import kafka.producer.KeyedMessage;
import kafka.producer.ProducerConfig;

import java.util.Date;
import java.util.Properties;
import java.util.Random;


    class TestProducer {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            long events = Long.parseLong(args[0]);
            Random rnd = new Random();

            Properties props = new Properties();
            props.put("metadata.broker.list", "abc.com/kafka1/:80,abc.com/kafka2/:80,abc.com/kafka3/:80");

            props.put("serializer.class", "kafka.serializer.StringEncoder");
            props.put("partitioner.class", "com.knx.adx.kafka.producer.SimplePartitioner");
            props.put("request.required.acks", "1");

            ProducerConfig config = new ProducerConfig(props);

            Producer<String, String> producer = new Producer<String, String>(config);

            for (long nEnvents = 0; nEnvents < events; nEnvents++) {
                long runtime = new Date().getTime();
                String ip = "192.168.2." + rnd.nextInt(255);
                String msg = runtime + ",www.example.com" + ip;
                KeyedMessage<String, String> data = new KeyedMessage<String, String>("page_visits", ip, msg);
                producer.send(data);
            }
            producer.close();
        }
    }
```

This is the error I get when I run my code.

```
Exception in thread "main" kafka.common.FailedToSendMessageException: Failed to send messages after 3 tries.
    at kafka.producer.async.DefaultEventHandler.handle(DefaultEventHandler.scala:90)
    at kafka.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:77)
    at kafka.javaapi.producer.Producer.send(Producer.scala:33)
    at com.knx.adx.kafka.producer.TestProducer.main(TestProducer.java:35)

line error producer.send(data);
```

Answer (score 2):

The configuration variable `metadata.broker.list` expects `host1:port1,host2:port2` instead of URLs. Try configuring different subdomain names for each broker like `kafka1.abc.com:80,kafka2.abc.com:80,kafka3.abc.com:80` and point those subdomains to the appropriate host. See the producer config section of [Kafka Configuration](https://kafka.apache.org/08/configuration.html)

> This is for bootstrapping and the producer will only use it for getting metadata (topics, partitions and replicas). The socket connections for sending the actual data will be established based on the broker information returned in the metadata. The format is host1:port1,host2:port2, and the list can be a subset of brokers or a VIP pointing to a subset of brokers.

Answer (score 1):

I would say that abc.com/kafka1/:80 is not a correct syntax. I think that the correct one should be abc.com:9092.

The url and port used in the metadata.broker.list property should be determined by what you set in the Kafka broker server.properties file (or whatever name you set when launching it).

Important values are:

```
# The port the socket server listens on
port=xxx
# Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces
#host.name=localhost

# Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, it uses the
# value for "host.name" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
# advertised.host.name=<hostname routable by clients>
```

Port by default is 9092, so check this one if you use 80.

Hope this helps.

Comment: in server it use port 9092 but ngix will forward port 80 to outside.

Comment: abc.com/kafka1/:80 syntax is incorrect. Check abc.com:80/kafka1/